# Multiple ajax calls ASP.MVC Async not working

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous

I have a view with multiple ajax calls that fills the view itself so it's a page, with some ajax calls to fill the content of that page.

I would like to make the call async so, all the calls stars at the same time, and are executed in the same time.

So if I have 6 calls i would like something like:

```
Start -18:01:01  -18:01:01  -18:01:01  -18:01:01  -18:01:01  -18:01:01
End  -18:01:15  -18:01:11  -18:01:09  -18:01:02  -18:01:02  -18:01:12
```

So that no method blocks another.

I tried puting : `[SessionState(SessionStateBehavior.Disabled)]`

and changing the controller to `AsyncController`

But the results that I get are:

```
GetChartFacturForComer Ini 12:17:30 - 829
GetChartFacturForComer fini 12:17:30 - 936

GetChartTotalMonthFacturation Ini 12:17:30 - 943
GetChartTotalMonthFacturation fIni 12:17:31 - 062

GetChartActivityForDate Ini 12:17:31 - 480
GetChartActivityForDate fIni 12:17:31 - 626

GetChartActivityForClientType Ini 12:17:31 - 980
GetChartActivityForClientType fIni 12:17:32 - 221

GridIndex Ini 12:17:34 - 575
GridIndex fIni 12:17:36 - 264

GetChartActivityForSales Ini 12:17:36 - 596
GetChartActivityForSales fIni 12:17:36 - 931
```

where Ini is the start of the method and fIni is the end. For the results it's clear that each method is executed AFTER the previous is finished, but that's not what I want...

I have only found the Session and asynccontroller solutions but it's not working. I'm missing something? I have to change something of my code?

Note: my methods are not asyn, but for what I have read, it's not needed.

My code:

```
public class AsyncBaseController  : AsyncController{
    // code
}

public class HomeController : AsyncBaseController{
    public JsonResult GetChartFacturForComer(){
        //LongMethod 1
    }
    public JsonResult GetChartTotalMonthFacturation(){
        //LongMethod 2
    }
    public JsonResult GetChartActivityForClientType(){
        //LongMethod 3
    }
    public JsonResult GetChartActivityForSales(){
        //LongMethod 4
    }
    public JsonResult GetChartActivityForDate(){
        //LongMethod 5
    }
    public JsonResult GridIndex(){
        //LongMethod 6
    }
}
```

Note: the calls are of kendo components, I don't know if this affects, but info is info.

**EDIT:**

As I have mentioned the calls in jquery come from kendo components and we are using the razor helpers so I have somthing like:

> @Html.Kendo().Chart("FirstChart").DataSource(ds =>
>   ds.Read("GetChartFacturForComer", "Home"));
>   @Html.Kendo().Chart("SecondChart").DataSource(ds =>
>   ds.Read("GetChartTotalMonthFacturation", "Home"));
>   @Html.Kendo().Chart("ThirdChart").DataSource(ds =>
>   ds.Read("GetChartActivityForClientType", "Home"));
>   @Html.Kendo().Chart("FourthChart").DataSource(ds =>
>   ds.Read("GetChartActivityForSales", "Home"));
>   @Html.Kendo().Chart("FifthChart").DataSource(ds =>
>   ds.Read("GetChartActivityForDate", "Home"));
>   @Html.Kendo().Grid("Grid").DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
>                           .Ajax().Read(read => read.Action("Grid", "Home"));

and in the Js

```
$.ajax({
            url: configuration.url,
            success: function (data) {
                Chart.LoadDynamicChartWithLegend(configuration.optionsToLoadDynamicChartWithLegend, data);
            }
        });
```

where I get the parameters of the chart and call the $.ajax for every chart.

Comment: Please also show your jQuery/JS code.

Comment: Show your JS. I think you're misunderstanding async and parallel execution

Comment: It is unlikely to be anything to do with your controller/server side code, that will by default process requests in parallel. Post you javascipt code as it looks like you are sending the requests sequentially.

Comment: Seems they are not executed in parallel on the client side. The only requirement on the server site is to disable session state.

Comment: I will look information regarding parallel execution in client side, it seems that i was confusing concepts as has said @VsevolodGoloviznin